Prove that $n \log n$ is a time-constructible function
I am reading [1]. On page 16 of [1], the authors wrote:

A function $T: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is time constructible if $T(n) \geq n$ and there is a TM $M$ that computes the function $x \mapsto \llcorner T(|x|) \lrcorner$ in time $T(n)$. (As usual, $\llcorner T(|x|) \lrcorner$ denotes the binary representation of the number $T(|x|)$.) Examples for time-constructible functions are $n$, $n \log n$, $n^2$, $2^n$.

In [1], $\mathbb{N}$ denotes the set of natural numbers (i.e., nonnegative integers). TM stands for Turing machine. The length of a string $x$ is denoted by $|x|$. Based on comments in [2], "time $T(n)$" should be "time $O(T(n))$". According to [1], the definition of $O$ is as follows:

Definition 0.2 (Big-Oh notation) If $f$, $g$ are two functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, then we (1) say that $f = O(g)$ if there exists a constant $c$ such that $f(n) \leq c \cdot g(n)$ for every sufficiently large $n$.

From page 1 of [1]:

We say that a condition $P(n)$ holds for sufficiently large $n$ if there exists some number $N$ such that $P(n)$ holds for every $n > N$ (for example, $2^n > 100 n^2$ for sufficiently large $n$).

[1] does not prove that $n$, $n \log n$, $n^2$, and $2^n$ are time-constructible functions. In [2], Bader Abu Radi proves that $n$ is a time-constructible function. I want to prove that $n \log n$ is also a time-constructible function. I find a similar question in [3], but I think that the answer in [3] does not provide such a proof. The answer in [3] does not prove that $n \log n \geq n$. It does not give the description of a TM that computes the function $x \mapsto \llcorner |x| \log |x| \lrcorner$ in time $O(n \log n)$, neither.
Therefore, I try to prove that $n \log n$ is a time-constructible function by myself.
First, I want to prove that $n \log n \geq n$. According to the definition of time-constructible functions in [1] (please see the first quote above), the domain and range of the function $T(n) = n \log n$ must both be $\mathbb{N}$. On page 16 of [1], footnote 5 wrotes:

Recall our convention that $\log$ is taken to base 2, and noninteger numbers are rounded up when necessary.

So I think $n \log n$ should be $n \lceil \log_2 n \rceil$. Clearly, $n$ must be greater than zero. When I set $n = 1$, I find that
$$ n \lceil \log_2 n \rceil = 1 \times \lceil \log_2 1 \rceil = 1 \times \lceil 0 \rceil = 1 \times 0 = 0. \tag{1}$$
So the inequality $n \lceil \log_2 n \rceil \geq n$ does not hold for $n = 1$. Then I do not know how to continue. Any comments and answers are welcome.
References
[1] S. Arora and B. Barak, Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach, Cambridge University Press, 2009.
[2] W.-C. Liu, "Prove that $n$ is a time-constructible function," cs.stackexchange.com, Jul. 10, 2024. [Online]. Available: Prove that $n$ is a time-constructible function. [Accessed Jul. 27, 2024].
[3] Dmv, “How can I prove that n . log n is a time constructible function? [closed],” math.stackexchange.com, Feb. 15, 2017. [Online]. Available: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145159/how-can-i-prove-that-n-log-n-is-a-time-constructible-function. [Accessed Jul. 27, 2024].

Some texts require that time constructible functions be non-decreasing. While others require the time constructible functions satisfy ()≥. Some texts do not even use asymptotic notation. So make sure to not mix terminologies from different sources. If you wait until you see the use of these theorems, I am pretty sure that 1log1 < 1 will not worry you.

To @BaderAbuRadi: OK, I understand. Thank you very much for your comment.

This should be simpler than showing that $n$ is time-constructible. Note that $|\llcorner n \lrcorner|$ is logarithmic in $n$. Then,
given input $1^n$, you can compute $\llcorner n \lrcorner$ in $O(n)$ steps (or even in $O(nlog n)$ steps), and compute $\llcorner logn \lrcorner$ in $O(logn)$ steps. Finally, proceed by multiplying the binary numbers  $\llcorner n \lrcorner$ and $\llcorner logn \lrcorner$ (see for example here).
Note that computing $\llcorner logn \lrcorner$ from $\llcorner n \lrcorner$ is not too trivial, yet not complicated either. As a hint, consider cases where where $n$ is a power of 2, and not.
I also leave the runtime analysis to you -- it almost follows from an immediate application of the linked questions.
Edit: to compute $\llcorner logn \lrcorner$ from $\llcorner n \lrcorner$, note that $log n$  equals $|\llcorner n \lrcorner| -1$ when $n$ is a power of $2$, and equals $|\llcorner n \lrcorner|$ otherwise. So we essentially need to compute the length of the input $\llcorner n \lrcorner$ in binary, which we already know how to do efficiently. Regarding the check whether $n$ is a power of 2, this is simple too, as we need to check whether $\llcorner n \lrcorner$ is of the form $10^*$.

Thank you very much for your answer. I will investigate how to compute $\llcorner \log n \lrcorner$ from $\llcorner n \lrcorner$ and analyze the runtime.

@Wei-ChengLiu You're welcome. If you encounter any problems, we can discuss it.

I have posted my solution on https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/169190/how-to-compute-llcorner-log-n-lrcorner-from-llcorner-n-lrcorner-using-a, please take a look.

@Wei-ChengLiu Did not read the details, but the general idea looks okay. The main point is to note that you need to compute the length of $\llcorner n \lrcorner$, and the other details are minor. You should be able to have a high-level discussion at this point, and dive into low-level details only when they matter, or if necessary. See my comment there.

@Wei-ChengLiu Also, see see how I edited the answer here. I can write in high-level, and convince you at the same time. Ofcourse, you need to make sure that you know how to handle the details, but I can convince you nonetheless.

OK, I understand. Thank you very much.

What is the meaning of $10^$? Based on the context, I guess $10^={1, 10, 100, ...}$, am I right?

Yes, it is a regular expression that generates the language ${ 10^n: n\geq 0}$.

OK, I understand. Thank you very much.
